# Lambdas and generics in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm playing with future java 8 release aka JDK 1.8.

And I found out that you can easily do

```
interface Foo { int method(); }
```

and use it like

```
Foo foo = () -> 3;
System.out.println("foo.method(); = " + foo.method());
```

which simply prints 3.

And I also found that there is a java.util.function.Function interface which does this in a more generic fashion. However this code won't compile

```
Function times3 = (Integer triple) -> 3 * triple;
Integer twelve = times3.map(4);
```

And it seems that I first have to do something like

```
interface IntIntFunction extends Function<Integer, Integer> {}

IntIntFunction times3 = (Integer triple) -> 3 * triple;
Integer twelve = times3.map(4);
```

So I'm wondering if there is another way to avoid the IntIntFunction step?

Comment: `Mapper<Integer, Integer> times3` maybe?

Comment: Now that I was beginning to understand generics, they come with THIS :-(...

Comment: In fact, in the latest build, there is no more an interface Mapper. It is called [Function](http://www.dalorzo.com/jdk8/javadocs/java/util/function/Function.html) now. There are some primitive versions called [IntFunction](http://www.dalorzo.com/jdk8/javadocs/java/util/function/IntFunction.html), [LongFunction](http://www.dalorzo.com/jdk8/javadocs/java/util/function/LongFunction.html) and [DoubleFunction](http://www.dalorzo.com/jdk8/javadocs/java/util/function/DoubleFunction.html).

Comment: `Function<Integer, Integer> times3` with current JDK8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@joop and @edwin thanks.

Based on latest release of JDK 8 this should do it.

```
IntFunction<Integer> times3 = (Integer triple) -> 3 * triple;
```

And in case you do not like  you can make it a bit more smooth with something like

```
IntFunction times3 = triple -> 3 * (Integer) triple;
```

So you do not need to specify a type or parentheses but you'll need to cast the parameter when you access it.

Comment: Wait. What is the cast doing there? Would it take `triple` to be Object? Do you recommend casting to `Integer` then, instead of `int`?

Comment: I don't think (int) cast will compile.

Comment: What's the difference between IntFunction<Something> and Function<Integer, Something> ?

Comment: IntFunction takes an int as a parameter. Function<Integer, ...> an Integer. It is classic java primitive vs its wrapper class.